# Безопасная передача данных

Tags: безопасность

Есть программа, которая должна сбрасывать информацию на сервер. Задача в том, чтобы информацию не подделали. Достаточно ли для защиты от любопытных людей вбить в программу строку симолов и с помощью нее делать crc, которая тем же способом проверяется на сервере? Заморачиваться с чем-то более сложным особого смысла не вижу. Информация открытая.

Comment: Нужно - подделают. Но может Вам хватит обычного ssl.

Comment: Мне кажется, в вопросах безопасности надо обратиться к специалисту, а не спрашивать на форумах. http://habrahabr.ru/post/181372/

Answer (score 1):

Обычная схема защиты в таком случае - сгенерировать сигнатуру и послать её вместе с данными. Сигнатура при этом получается как результат необратимого шифрования строки, составленной из передаваемых данных и пароля, известного получателю и отправителю. Получатель не расшифровывает сигнатуру (это невозможно), а создаёт её заново: запрос он получил, а пароль он знает. Подробнее тут: [Освоение криптографии - 3: SHA-1](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2010/07/3-sha-1.html).

Comment: Так и делаю.